# Mootools Div overlay

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

could someone maybe give me a small hint on how to do this with mootools.

Basically i have a div like

```
<div id="center-panel" style="height: 200px; width 200px; background: green;"></div>
```

i basically want this div tag hidden by default, and then once the user has been on the website for like two minutes i want the div tag to display>

Answer (score 1):

In an onload handler for your site, use `setTimeout()` to show the div after 2 minutes:

```
function showDiv(){
    $('center-panel').setStyle('display', 'block');
};
setTimeout(showDiv, 60 * 1000 * 2);
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/BTbuQ/) with a 2 second delay rather than 2 minutes.

Comment: thankyou so much for that !!!! how could i add some affects so that the div overlays everything else and kind of slides up to be displayed

Comment: To get it to overlay everything, set it to `position: absolute` with a `z-index` value higher than all your other elements.  You can then morph its `left` and `top` values to move it around.  The morph docs can get you started on that part: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph

Comment: mootools abstracts `setTimeout` to `function.delay(nnn)` - I wouldn't use a named function either. check out http://jsfiddle.net/BTbuQ/1/ - it should really be refactored to be a reusable pattern but this is close, ensures compatibility with jquery etc and is more mooish

Comment: here's an example via an Element prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/BTbuQ/2/ and a fade in effect